# read xml file with php

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file  in this format

```
 "note.xml"
      <currencies>
     <currency name="US dollar" code_alpha="USD" code_numeric="840" />
         <currency name="Euro" code_alpha="EUR" code_numeric="978" />

      </currencies>
```

PHP CODE

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("note.xml");

echo $xml->name. "<br>";             --no output
echo $xml->code_alpha. "<br>";        --no output
echo $xml->code_numeric . "<br>";        --no output

     print_r($xml);
```

output of print_r($xml)-->SimpleXMLElement Object ( [currency] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => US dollar [code_alpha] => USD [code_numeric] => 840 ) )

I didnt get any output for the ECHO statements 
I tried 'simplexml_load_file' and tried reading from it but it doesnt work. Please tell me what php code should I use to read from this format of XML file.

Comment: Why do you say that `simplexml_load_file` didn't work? show us your php code first.

Comment: `echo $xml->name. "<br>";
echo $xml->code_alpha . "<br>";
echo $xml->code_numeric. "<br>";`     i tried this as per W3schools  but got a blank output .....

Comment: never, EVER consult w3schools again. It's often wrong and misleading.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using DomDocument:

```
<?php
$str = <<<XML
<currencies>
    <currency name="US dollar" code_alpha="USD" code_numeric="840" />
    <currency name="Euro" code_alpha="EUR" code_numeric="978" />
</currencies>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($str);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('currency') as $currency)
{
    echo $currency->getAttribute('name'), "\n";
    echo $currency->getAttribute('code_alpha'), "\n";
    echo $currency->getAttribute('code_numeric'), "\n";
    echo "+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+\n";
}
?>
```

[**Live DEMO.**](https://eval.in/39440)

Using simplexml:

```
<?php
$str = <<<XML
<currencies>
    <currency name="US dollar" code_alpha="USD" code_numeric="840" />
    <currency name="Euro" code_alpha="EUR" code_numeric="978" />
</currencies>
XML;


$currencies = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
foreach($currencies as $currency)
{
    echo $currency['name'], "\n";
    echo $currency['code_alpha'], "\n";
    echo $currency['code_numeric'], "\n";
    echo "+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+\n";
}
?>
```

**[Live DEMO.](https://eval.in/39438)**

Comment: is it same code for loading from xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DomDocument to achieve this objective.

Check on this post http://www.developersnote.com/2013/12/how-to-read-xml-file-in-php.html

```
$objDOM = new DOMDocument();

//Load xml file into DOMDocument variable
$objDOM->load("../configuration.xml");

//Find Tag element "config" and return the element to variable $node
$node = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("config");

//looping if tag config have more than one
foreach ($node as $searchNode) {
    $dbHost = $searchNode->getAttribute('host');
    $dbUser = $searchNode->getAttribute('userdb');
    $dbPass = $searchNode->getAttribute('dbpass');
    $dbDatabase = $searchNode->getAttribute('database');
}
```