# read XML file with php and simplexml

Tags: php, xml

one more n00b here :)

i have a xml file that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE BPS SYSTEM "bpml.dtd">
<BPS Created="2012-04-24 11:40:41">
<Machine SerialNumber="" Site="" SoftwareRelease="MAP_248204031" VersionInfo="" Name="" Type="BPS200">
<ParameterSection Number="6" StartTime="2012-04-24 11:23:01" EndTime="1970-01-01 00:00:00">
<Operator></Operator>
<HeadercardUnit HeaderCardID="1706539" DepositID="01706539" StartTime="2012-04-24 11:39:57" MilliSec="0" EndTime="2012-04-24 11:40:40" Rejects="NO">
<Counter Currency="HRK" DenomID="22550" Value="200" Quality="Fit" Output="Stacked" Number="192"></Counter>
<Counter Currency="HRK" DenomID="22550" Value="200" Quality="Unfit" Output="Stacked" Number="7"></Counter>
</HeadercardUnit>
</ParameterSection>
</Machine>
</BPS>
```

i need to put values from it to the mysql db but i do not know how to read nested values from that xml.

here is what i tried so far just to see what's happening:

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file($filename);
if ($xml !== FALSE) {
    $row[] = $xml->Machine->ParameterSection->HeadercardUnit; // tried to throw values in the array - no go
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo 'item: ' . $item . "<br>";
    }
}
```

but that does not work.

here is my insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO counttable (DenomID, Quality, Number, headercard) VALUES (22550, 'Fit', 192, 1706539)
```

probably using associative array of values from XML. something like this

```
$count = array('HeaderCardID'='1706539', 'DenomID'='22550', 'Quality'='Fit', 'Number'='192')
```

and then:

```
INSERT INTO counttable (DenomID, Quality, Number, headercard) VALUES ('$count[1]', '$count[2]', '$count[3]', '$count[0]')
```

and so on for every Counter row in the xml. it can be many Counter rows in single xml.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon counter corrected.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran i'd like to get array of all keys and values or variables with values. something that i can use to put in the db

Comment: here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917539/read-xml-file-with-php is very similar question but the answer does not work with xml files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any extra checking if a node exists, I believe this should be it.

The trick is to get the children of HeadercardUnit and iterate them. Then you can get attributes of each Counter element. Attributes have a name but the value is a PHP SimpleXMLElement instance. In order to get a nice value, we cast it to string.

You'll end up with an array of arrays. Each one of those can be saved in the database.

```
 $xml = @simplexml_load_file($filename);    
 $to_save_array = [];

 if($xml)
 {
    // looping all children, assumed it always exists
    foreach($xml->Machine->ParameterSection->HeadercardUnit->children() as $counter)
    {
        // data of this Counter record
        $record_data = [];

        // getting the attributes
        foreach($counter->attributes() as $name => $value)
        {
            // casting a SimpleXMLElement to string yields the text value of the node
            $record_data[$name] = (string)$value;
        }

        $to_save_array[] = $record_data;
    }
}

var_dump($to_save_array);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: PHP docs for SimpleXMLElement: [link](http://it1.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)
For attributes: [link](http://it1.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

Comment: thx fle. that was exactly what i needed! for anyone else reading this, i had to change $record_data = []; and $to_save_array = []; to $record_data = array(); and $to_save_array = array(); thx again!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$xml = @simplexml_load_file('asd.xml');
if ($xml !== FALSE) {
    foreach ($xml as $key => $item) {
        foreach($item->attributes() as $attr => $val){
            print_r($val);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Adapt it to your needs.

`$key` is "element2" and "element3";

`$item` is the element itself;

`$attr` is keyXY (e.g. key21, key22);

`$val` is the value of the attribute, valueXY (e.g. value21, value22).

Comment: thx Lorenzo. this does not work for me. probably cause i've poorly explained my question. i've edited the question and accompanied it with real data so maybe it is more cleare.