# How to read data from XML file using php

Tags: php, xml, api, loops, xmlreader

**I want to read data from the below xml file using php code.**

below is the XML file and i want to read data from it.

```
<availabilityRS xmlns="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/messages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/messages">
<auditData processTime="4331" timestamp="2016-12-08 11:05:49.211" requestHost="182.48.20.151" serverId="sa37AUX3ROLBLIS.env" environment="[int]" release="8629cf6ef0a2deed178b86daa0e13c79b5c99237" internal="0|D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30|UK|06|1|39||||||||||||25||1~1~2~0|||||vgw3t5723ryk95m4q58m3g87||"/>
<hotels checkIn="2016-12-15" checkOut="2016-12-16" total="1">
<hotel code="1070" name="Armadams" categoryCode="4EST" categoryName="4 STARS" destinationCode="PMI" destinationName="Majorca" zoneCode="10" zoneName="Palma" latitude="39.568861" longitude="2.630294" minRate="69.34" maxRate="224.00" currency="EUR">
<rooms>
<room code="DBT.ST" name="Double or Twin STANDARD">
<rates>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|DBT.ST|CG- FIT|RO||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="69.34" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|94855|3" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="69.34" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|DBT.ST|CG- MERCHANT|RO||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="70.32" sellingRate="80.00" hotelSellingRate="80.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="8.00" commissionVAT="1.68" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="80.00" hotelAmount="80.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|DBT.ST|CG- MERCHANT|RO||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="69.79" sellingRate="80.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="69.79" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|DBT.ST|CG- FIT|BB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="96.18" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|94855|3" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="BB" boardName="BED AND BREAKFAST" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="96.18" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|DBT.ST|CG- MERCHANT|BB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="96.69" sellingRate="110.00" hotelSellingRate="110.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="11.00" commissionVAT="2.31" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="BB" boardName="BED AND BREAKFAST" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="110.00" hotelAmount="110.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|DBT.ST|CG- MERCHANT|BB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="95.97" sellingRate="110.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="BB" boardName="BED AND BREAKFAST" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="95.97" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|DBT.ST|CG- FIT|HB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="140.92" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|94855|3" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="HB" boardName="HALF BOARD" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="140.92" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|DBT.ST|CG- MERCHANT|HB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="140.64" sellingRate="160.00" hotelSellingRate="160.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="16.00" commissionVAT="3.36" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="HB" boardName="HALF BOARD" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="160.00" hotelAmount="160.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|DBT.ST|CG- MERCHANT|HB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="139.57" sellingRate="160.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="HB" boardName="HALF BOARD" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="139.57" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
</rates>
</room>
<room code="DBT.SU" name="Double or Twin SUPERIOR">
<rates>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|DBT.SU|CG- FIT|RO||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="91.70" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|94855|3" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="91.70" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|DBT.SU|CG- MERCHANT|RO||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="93.17" sellingRate="106.00" hotelSellingRate="106.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="10.60" commissionVAT="2.23" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="106.00" hotelAmount="106.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|DBT.SU|CG- MERCHANT|RO||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="92.47" sellingRate="106.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="92.47" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|DBT.SU|CG- FIT|BB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="118.54" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|94855|3" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="BB" boardName="BED AND BREAKFAST" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="118.54" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|DBT.SU|CG- MERCHANT|BB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="118.65" sellingRate="136.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="BB" boardName="BED AND BREAKFAST" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="118.65" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|DBT.SU|CG- MERCHANT|BB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="119.54" sellingRate="136.00" hotelSellingRate="136.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="13.60" commissionVAT="2.86" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="BB" boardName="BED AND BREAKFAST" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="136.00" hotelAmount="136.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|DBT.SU|CG- FIT|HB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="163.28" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|94855|3" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="HB" boardName="HALF BOARD" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="163.28" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|DBT.SU|CG- MERCHANT|HB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="163.49" sellingRate="186.00" hotelSellingRate="186.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="18.60" commissionVAT="3.91" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="HB" boardName="HALF BOARD" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="186.00" hotelAmount="186.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|DBT.SU|CG- MERCHANT|HB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="162.25" sellingRate="186.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="HB" boardName="HALF BOARD" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="162.25" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
</rates>
</room>
<room code="TPL.ST" name="TRIPLE STANDARD">
<rates>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|TPL.ST|CG- MERCHANT|RO||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="94.93" sellingRate="108.00" hotelSellingRate="108.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="10.80" commissionVAT="2.27" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="108.00" hotelAmount="108.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|TPL.ST|CG- MERCHANT|RO||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="94.22" sellingRate="108.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="94.22" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|TPL.ST|CG- MERCHANT|BB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="121.30" sellingRate="138.00" hotelSellingRate="138.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="13.80" commissionVAT="2.90" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="BB" boardName="BED AND BREAKFAST" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="138.00" hotelAmount="138.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|TPL.ST|CG- MERCHANT|BB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="120.40" sellingRate="138.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="BB" boardName="BED AND BREAKFAST" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="120.40" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|TPL.ST|CG- MERCHANT|HB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="165.25" sellingRate="188.00" hotelSellingRate="188.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="18.80" commissionVAT="3.95" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="HB" boardName="HALF BOARD" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="188.00" hotelAmount="188.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|TPL.ST|CG- MERCHANT|HB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="164.00" sellingRate="188.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="HB" boardName="HALF BOARD" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="164.00" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
</rates>
</room>
<room code="JSU.ST" name="JUNIOR SUITE STANDARD">
<rates>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|JSU.ST|CG- FIT|RO||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="123.02" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|94855|3" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="123.02" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|JSU.ST|CG- MERCHANT|RO||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="126.58" sellingRate="144.00" hotelSellingRate="144.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="14.40" commissionVAT="3.02" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="144.00" hotelAmount="144.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|JSU.ST|CG- MERCHANT|RO||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="125.62" sellingRate="144.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="125.62" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|JSU.ST|CG- FIT|BB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="149.86" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|94855|3" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="BB" boardName="BED AND BREAKFAST" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="149.86" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|JSU.ST|CG- MERCHANT|BB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="151.80" sellingRate="174.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="BB" boardName="BED AND BREAKFAST" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="151.80" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|JSU.ST|CG- MERCHANT|BB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="152.95" sellingRate="174.00" hotelSellingRate="174.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="17.40" commissionVAT="3.65" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="BB" boardName="BED AND BREAKFAST" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="174.00" hotelAmount="174.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|JSU.ST|CG- FIT|HB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="194.60" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|94855|3" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="HB" boardName="HALF BOARD" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="194.60" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|JSU.ST|CG- MERCHANT|HB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="196.90" sellingRate="224.00" hotelSellingRate="224.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="22.40" commissionVAT="4.70" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="HB" boardName="HALF BOARD" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="224.00" hotelAmount="224.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|JSU.ST|CG- MERCHANT|HB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="195.40" sellingRate="224.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="HB" boardName="HALF BOARD" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="195.40" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
</rates>
</room>
<room code="QUA.ST" name="QUADRUPLE STANDARD">
<rates>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|QUA.ST|CG- MERCHANT|RO||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="115.15" sellingRate="131.00" hotelSellingRate="131.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="13.10" commissionVAT="2.75" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="131.00" hotelAmount="131.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|QUA.ST|CG- MERCHANT|RO||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="114.28" sellingRate="131.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="114.28" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|QUA.ST|CG- MERCHANT|BB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="141.52" sellingRate="161.00" hotelSellingRate="161.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="16.10" commissionVAT="3.38" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="BB" boardName="BED AND BREAKFAST" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="161.00" hotelAmount="161.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|QUA.ST|CG- MERCHANT|BB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="140.46" sellingRate="161.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="BB" boardName="BED AND BREAKFAST" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="140.46" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|W|1|1070|QUA.ST|CG- MERCHANT|HB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="184.06" sellingRate="211.00" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="HB" boardName="HALF BOARD" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="184.06" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
<rate rateKey="20161215|20161216|H|1|1070|QUA.ST|CG- MERCHANT|HB||1~2~0||N@D4A049C5629A4D3B81ED8C1609B92A30" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="185.47" sellingRate="211.00" hotelSellingRate="211.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" hotelMandatory="true" allotment="99" commission="21.10" commissionVAT="4.43" commissionPCT="10.00" rateCommentsId="1|90440|96" paymentType="AT_HOTEL" packaging="false" boardCode="HB" boardName="HALF BOARD" rooms="1" adults="2" children="0" childrenAges="">
<cancellationPolicies>
<cancellationPolicy amount="211.00" hotelAmount="211.00" hotelCurrency="EUR" from="2016-12-12T23:59:00+01:00"/>
</cancellationPolicies>
</rate>
</rates>
</room>
</rooms>
<creditCards>
<creditCard code="VI" name="VISA-SSL" paymentType="AT_HOTEL"/>
<creditCard code="AE" name="AMEX-SSL" paymentType="AT_HOTEL"/>
<creditCard code="MC" name="ECMC-SSL" paymentType="AT_HOTEL"/>
<creditCard code="DC" name="DINERS-SSL" paymentType="AT_HOTEL"/>
</creditCards>
</hotel>
</hotels>
</availabilityRS>
```

I have tried like this code to retrieve data from the xml.

Below I have attached the code used to retrieve data from the xml

```
$xml  = simplexml_load_string("myxml.xml");
foreach($xml as $hotel) { 
   echo "Hotel Name: ".$hotel->hotel['name']."<br>";
   echo "Hotel Category: ".$hotel->hotel['categoryName']."<br>";
   echo "Hotel Destination: ".$hotel->hotel['destinationName']."<br>";
   echo "Room Name: ".$hotel->hotel->rooms->room['name']."<br>";
   //echo "<br>"; 
}
```

But the result is

> ```
> Hotel Name: 
> Hotel Category: 
> Hotel Destination: 
> Room Name: 
> Hotel Name: Armadams
> Hotel Category: 4 STARS
> Hotel Destination: Majorca
> Room Name: Double or Twin STANDARD
> ```

All room data are not getting and displaying, is there any other way to read data from xml?

Comment: It would be useful to see how you loaded `$xml` as well as how you try and process it

Comment: I just edited the $xml is added into the question

Comment: So apart from trying to access an attribute that does not exist `echo "Hotel Name: ".$hotel->hotel['name']."<br>"` What is your problem. What are you trying to produce as output. [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read xml file with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917539/read-xml-file-with-php)

Comment: From the xml, there are 5 room are showing, but when my code is only showing 1 room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample code below can help:

```
<?php
$availabilityrs = simplexml_load_file('temp.xml');
$hotel = $availabilityrs->hotels->hotel;
$room_nodes = $hotel->rooms->room;
foreach ($room_nodes as $room) {
    echo "Hotel Name: ".$hotel['name']."\n";
    echo "Hotel Category: ".$hotel['categoryName']."\n";
    echo "Hotel Destination: ".$hotel['destinationName']."\n";
    echo "Room Name: ".$room['name']."\n";
}
```

please refer [this manul](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php):

> When multiple instances of an element exist as children of a single parent element, normal iteration techniques apply.

If `hotel` is mutiple, you should iterate it too.

Comment: I have added more hotels in the [myxmlfile](http://www.medhyaftravel.com/api/api3/myxmlfile.xml),

All hotels are showing, but only one room is showing.

Answer (score 0):

`$xml` in your code probably refers to root element, that is `<availabilityRS>`. You need to change your loop to get to `<hotels>` and `<hotel>s.` and their rooms. Also you'll need to change `simplexml_load_string` to `simplexml_load_file` if you are reading XML data from a file:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(__DIR__.'/myxml.xml');

foreach ($xml->hotels[0] as $hotel) {
    echo $hotel['name']."<br>";
    echo $hotel['categoryName']."<br>";
    echo $hotel['destinationName']."<br>";
    echo "rooms:<br>";
    foreach ($hotel->rooms[0] as $room) {
        echo $room['name']."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes its working, but I have small problem. null data is showing,

please click the link

[link]http://www.medhyaftravel.com/api/api3/test3.php

Comment: some of the fields are empty, means first loop is not showing and the second loop is working. why it happen?

Comment: Cannot tell without seeing the XML file you use.

Comment: Did you notice warning produced in the link you've given?

Comment: [myxmlfile](http://www.medhyaftravel.com/api/api3/myxmlfile.xml)

you can collect my xml file here

Comment: @Midhun: If I run my code with your XML file, it outputs just one set of information, so there must be a problem with your code in test3.php. Maybe you run something twice...

Answer (score 0):

Traversing XML elements the object-oriented way could be messy for some people. It's better have them converted to array elements and it then makes easier to iterate through them. Here is the code to convert the XML object to array and traversing through them:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('myxml.xml');
$xml = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);
$hotel = $xml['hotels']['hotel'];

foreach($hotel['rooms'] as $rooms) {
    foreach($rooms as $room) {
        echo "<p>Hotel Name: {$hotel['@attributes']['name']}</p>";
        echo "<p>Hotel Category: {$hotel['@attributes']['categoryName']}</p>";
        echo "<p>Hotel Destination: {$hotel['@attributes']['destinationName']}</p>";
        echo "<p>Room Name: {$room['@attributes']['name']}</p>";
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, I got an error in for loop.

**Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

[link](http://www.medhyaftravel.com/api/api3/test3.php)

Comment: [XML](http://www.medhyaftravel.com/api/api3/myxmlfile.xml)

XML has been updated, but added some more data into the xml, not changed the format.

Comment: Whenever you work with variables and get unexpected output, debug those variables using any of these functions `var_dump`, `var_export` and `print_r` to analyse variables information. Debug `$hotel` variable before passing it to `foreach`. So, you could easily figure out the problem.