# print xml data list in table php

Tags: php, json, xml, xslt

I want to print xml data which is returned by a website to table

```
$url="http://rss.careerjet.com/rss?s=java&l=delhi";
$xml= file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
foreach ($data as $row) {
     echo $row['title'];
 }
```

however i am getting some error unable to find object title;

please help

Comment: you need to parse XML have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917539/read-xml-file-with-php and json_decode is used for parsing json.

Comment: `json_decode()` isn't meant for XML.

Comment: can you give me sample code, the above link isnt helping me out