# How to get specific data from XML API url using PHP

Tags: php, xml, api

I can display all values in it but I just want to know how to display specific data from this url. Can I display diesel price from this url?

I have tried `$getdata->{'gpp:diesel'}` but it display none

Here is the display of the XML API

```
<gpp:data xmlns:gpp="http://www.globalpetrolprices.com">
  <gpp:element>
    <gpp:country code="MY">Malaysia</gpp:country>
    <gpp:date>2019-05-13</gpp:date>
    <gpp:currency>MYR</gpp:currency>
    <gpp:diesel>2.18</gpp:diesel>
  </gpp:element>
</gpp:data>
```

Here is the code :

```
<?php
   $url = 'https://www.globalpetrolprices.com/api_gpp.php?cnt=MY&ind=dp&prd=latest&uid=1437&uidc=13fc5a9f3a45102997db4d4698669ac7';

   $getdata = file_get_contents($url);

   echo "DIESEL PRICE PER LITRE : ".$getdata."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: There are many stackoverflow examples on how to read XML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read xml file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917539/read-xml-file-with-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: use dom library of php below is the link   https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_load_file.asp

Comment: None of it works. But I solve the problem myself. Answer updated :)